# How to deploy ruby script?

Tags: ruby, deployment

I have written simple ruby websocket script, using `em-websocket`, which listening folder for new files, parse them and send to clients.

When I want to test it, I just put `ruby filename.rb` in terminal and start my websocket server. I am using rvm and I guess it has some integrated server maybe WEBrick like rails has.

Now I have a question, how can I deploy my script and which server should I use?
Can I do it by install RVM on my server and required gems, and then run my script with bash on startup? Will it work that way?

Also is it good to use `em-websocket` because developers have stopped working on it?

EDIT: By the way I want to run my server on ubuntu server so I don't need `.exe`

Comment: I don't think this is really a duplicate: That question asks how to deploy without installing an interpreter.  This question just asks how to deploy _at all_.

Comment: A quick search for the gem throws this https://github.com/dansimpson/em-websocket-server. What have you tried?

Comment: normally you don't put rvm on the server. hopefully you are using a gemfile. In this case you copy the files over, bundle install and bundle exec. You only need to have ruby, gem, and bundler on the target server.

Comment: @Mircea Why not use rvm on the server?  It works very well there.

Comment: @WayneConrad the reason you don't want rvm there is because it adds another layer of complexity you don't need. in a development setting you may need to switch between rubies / do not-so-great stuff but on the server you usually want to minimize complexity.